How to indent new line in IntelliJ after curly brackets
How can I get automatic indent on new line after pressing Enter after curly brackets in Java IntelliJ. Like when Entering inside Class or Method. If anyone can help. So is there any specific settings that regulates what happens when you press Enter after opening curly bracket?
I am working on Windows 10 IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4. Ultimate Edition
public class Person implements IPerson { //When I press enter here
//I get here
  //But I want to get here


When I click on 2 spaces in the bottom-right corner I get this settings

https://youtu.be/nKr3JaSjIT8

That's default behavior.

What is default behaviour? What I want? I didn't have this problem then I updated IntelliJ or maybe changed some settings and now I don't know how to get it back.

Are you saying that text in my picture doesn't describe the problem adequately? And if I add more text that adds no new information then people will be just loosing time reading it.

@ivoronline No, an image does not describe your issue. Post your code as code, not as an image.

IntelliJ has 'code style' settings you can manually adjust to fit your preferences. When in IntelliJ go to all settings, find the Editor dropdown, then go to Code Style and Java in there you'll find indentation settings you can change to meet your preferences.

If that doesn't work, in the bottom right corner of the text editor you should see text that says '0 spaces'. If you select it you can change it to 'Indent new lines with 4 spaces'.

See the manual for code style for Java.
See how to reset your code style settings.
See how to reformat your code.

I am aware of these settings and was playing around with them by nothing worked.

Understood, in that case, in the bottom right of the text-editor you should see text that says '0-space'. If you click it, you can select 'indent new lines with 4 spaces' and it should solve your problem.

It already says two spaces and when I click on it it gets me to that configuration Page you pasted.

Could you send a screenshot of what shows in the bottom right of your code space, as well as where it takes you when you click on it?
Also, what operating system and version of IntelliJ are you running?

I have added info to the question

From your screenshot it would appear lines are already indenting.
If you did this manually, could you please create a new program and take a quick video of what happens when you press enter?

I have restarted PC and recorded screen.
https://youtu.be/nKr3JaSjIT8

I have also created new Empty project, created java Class and it behaves the same.

Do you have any plugins installed?

Smart Align, Lombok, AI Assistant and others that were automatically installed. If I disable these 3 it behaves the same.
